# AppleScript - Using information in the cells of an Excel file as the initializing attributes of a class in Xcode

Tags: xcode, excel, applescript, document, cells

As of right now I have the code:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"

-- put the complete set of data into a list of lists (i.e., 2 dimensions -> columns of rows)
set range1 to range "B2:H7686"
tell active sheet to set myData to value of range1
-- now access a specific cell's data
set myRow to 7
set myCol to 3
set myVal to item {myCol} of item {myRow} of myData

end tell
```

creating a double array with elements by row and then by column. So if my Excel cells look like this:

**| A1 | A2 | A3 |**

**| B1 | B2 | B3 |**

my variable myVar will be an array that will look like this:

**{{"A1", "A2", "A3"}, {"B1", "B2", "B3"}}**

What I want to do now is take an existing project, we'll call it example_project, with an existing .m file, we'll call it example_m.m, and write each element of the arrays within myVar to be attribute of an object.

For example, if my array is the same array as mentioned before and I'm initializing an example object with those values as the attributes it should look something like this in Xcode:

```
exampleObjectA = [[exampleClass alloc] init];
[exampleObjectA initExampleClass:@"A1" secondAttribute:@"A2" thirdAttribute:@"A3"];

exampleObjectB = [[exampleClass alloc] init];
[exampleObjectB initExampleClass:@"B1" secondAttribute:@"B2" thirdAttribute:@"B3"];
```

What I'm asking for is what would give me these exact lines of code, pre-written into Xcode. I have about 45000 cells worth of data that I'm trying to put into an application but I don't want to do it manually for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You are using exampleObjectA with many properties, that you are setting while `init`ing it. I would suggest you to make an array of KVP and go on to add it.

As you are passing @"A1", @"A2" as string, you can make a loop and use

```
for(NSInteger i=1; i<=myVar.count; i++){
    NSString *cellReference=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"A%ld,i];
    //then call a method to update your exampleObjectA
    //add this to array or KVP
}
```